# Angular Cli project set up

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

We have a angular 2 application where we are using some native css components which has some js files in it, there are wrapper to convert it to angular 2 components. I want to create a new angular 4 project using angular cli and reuse those components but i am getting `"module not found: as below` error while compiling, The difference with angular 2 project is they have a setting in systemjs.config.js file as

```
'my-ui-components': {
                format: 'global',
                main: 'main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                map: {
                    '/patterns/components': './patterns/components',
                }
            },
```

I dont have systemjs.config.js in angular-cli project so tried to copy this settings in angular-cli.json, but i am still getting the same error

```
 ERROR in ./src/my-ui-components/main.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/patterns/components/options/module.js' in '/Users/me/repo/my-app/src/my-ui-components'
@ ./src/my-ui-components/main.js 2757:10-2758:66 3371:10-3373:66 3589:10-3591:66 5279:10-5282:68 6017:10-6018:108
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Angular Project from scratch (using angular-cli), and then move your files from the old project into the new one.
The components you want to use (the .js files) can be referenced in the "scripts" section of your angular-cli.json file. These will get bundled together with your application.

If that doesn't work, one option would be to put them in the "assets" folder, so it will be deployed as additional resources for your application, though it is not the recommended approach.

Comment: @the.fabrico i tried both but no luck, still getting the same error :(

Comment: one of my js file is referring to other js files do you i tried to import all js files in scripts but still same .